# Runtime version issue using Mono on Linux Debian

Tags: linux, mono, debian, exe, wine

I am trying to run an executable program on Linux via Mono (as Wine will not comply), and I am given this output. I have searched and do not know what to do:

> WARNING: The runtime version supported by this application is unavailable.
>   Using default runtime: v4.0.30319
>   cannot open file /root/Desktop/tool\GeoIP.dat
>   System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Directory '/root/Desktop/tool\plugin\' not found.
>     at System.IO.Directory.ValidateDirectoryListing (System.String path, System.String searchPattern, System.Boolean& stop) <0x7f11f1ba74c0 + 0x0019c> in :0 
>     at System.IO.Directory.GetFileSystemEntries (System.String path, System.String searchPattern, FileAttributes mask, FileAttributes attrs) <0x7f11f1ba7700 + 0x00066> in :0 
>     at System.IO.Directory.GetFiles (System.String path, System.String searchPattern) <0x7f11f1ba6d50 + 0x00018> in :0 
>     at njRAT.Form1. (System.Object , System.EventArgs ) <0x4102ea90 + 0x006ea> in :0 
>     at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnLoad (System.EventArgs e) <0x410218f0 + 0x00071> in :0 
>     at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnLoadInternal (System.EventArgs e) <0x410216d0 + 0x0007f> in :0 
>   System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
>     at  +. () <0x4103f510 + 0x001e6> in :0 
>     at njRAT.Form1. (System.Object , System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs ) <0x4103e250 + 0x000ab> in :0 
>     at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnFormClosing (System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs e) <0x4103e1c0 + 0x00065> in :0 
>     at System.Windows.Forms.Form.FireClosingEvents (CloseReason reason, Boolean cancel) <0x4103e070 + 0x0009d> in :0 
>     at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.Windows.Forms.Form:FireClosingEvents (System.Windows.Forms.CloseReason,bool)
>     at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Exit (System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e) <0x4103db20 + 0x001b7> in :0 
>     at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Exit () <0x4103dae0 + 0x00027> in :0 
>     at System.Windows.Forms.Application.OnThreadException (System.Exception t) <0x4103d630 + 0x00147> in :0 
>     at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnLoadInternal (System.EventArgs e) <0x410216d0 + 0x00097> in :0 
>     at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnCreateControl () <0x41020ef0 + 0x0004f> in :0 
>     at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl () <0x412a3170 + 0x0011f> in :0 
>     at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmShowWindow (System.Windows.Forms.Message& m) <0x412ab7b0 + 0x00167> in :0 
>     at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc (System.Windows.Forms.Message& m) <0x412aa4a0 + 0x002d7> in :0 
>     at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc (System.Windows.Forms.Message& m) <0x4101b3b0 + 0x00013> in :0 
>     at System.Windows.Forms.ContainerControl.WndProc (System.Windows.Forms.Message& m) <0x4101b330 + 0x0005b> in :0 
>     at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WndProc (System.Windows.Forms.Message& m) <0x4101af50 + 0x00257> in :0 
>     at System.Windows.Forms.Control+ControlWindowTarget.OnMessage (System.Windows.Forms.Message& m) <0x412aa470 + 0x00024> in :0 
>     at System.Windows.Forms.Control+ControlNativeWindow.WndProc (System.Windows.Forms.Message& m) <0x412aa430 + 0x00036> in :0 
>     at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.WndProc (IntPtr hWnd, Msg msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam) <0x412a8d70 + 0x0031c> in :0
>
> Unhandled Exception:
>   System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
>     at  +. () <0x4103f510 + 0x001e6> in :0 
>     at njRAT.Form1. (System.Object , System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs ) <0x4103e250 + 0x000ab> in :0 
>     at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnFormClosing (System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs e) <0x4103e1c0 + 0x00065> in :0 
>     at System.Windows.Forms.Form.FireClosingEvents (CloseReason reason, Boolean cancel) <0x4103e070 + 0x0009d> in :0 
>     at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.Windows.Forms.Form:FireClosingEvents (System.Windows.Forms.CloseReason,bool)
>     at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Exit (System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e) <0x4103db20 + 0x001b7> in :0 
>     at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Exit () <0x4103dae0 + 0x00027> in :0 
>     at System.Windows.Forms.Application.OnThreadException (System.Exception t) <0x4103d630 + 0x00147> in :0 
>     at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.OnThreadException (System.Exception e) <0x41040a70 + 0x00013> in :0 
>     at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.WndProc (IntPtr hWnd, Msg msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam) <0x412a8d70 + 0x00b51> in :0 
>     at System.Windows.Forms.XplatUIX11.SendMessage (IntPtr hwnd, Msg message, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam) <0x412a8650 + 0x0044f> in :0 
>     at System.Windows.Forms.XplatUIX11.MapWindow (System.Windows.Forms.Hwnd hwnd, WindowType windows) <0x412ab2d0 + 0x001f3> in :0 
>     at System.Windows.Forms.XplatUIX11.CreateWindow (System.Windows.Forms.CreateParams cp) <0x412a37e0 + 0x00c53> in :0 
>     at System.Windows.Forms.XplatUI.CreateWindow (System.Windows.Forms.CreateParams cp) <0x412a37b0 + 0x0001f> in :0 
>     at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.CreateHandle (System.Windows.Forms.CreateParams cp) <0x412a3700 + 0x0003f> in :0 
>     at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateHandle () <0x412a3420 + 0x00069> in :0 
>     at System.Windows.Forms.Form.CreateHandle () <0x41019c40 + 0x00027> in :0 
>     at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl () <0x412a3170 + 0x00087> in :0 
>     at System.Windows.Forms.Control.SetVisibleCore (Boolean value) <0x412b4bb0 + 0x00083> in :0 
>     at System.Windows.Forms.Form.SetVisibleCore (Boolean value) <0x41019420 + 0x00317> in :0 
>     at System.Windows.Forms.Control.set_Visible (Boolean value) <0x412b4b30 + 0x00032> in :0 
>     at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.Windows.Forms.Control:set_Visible (bool)
>     at System.Windows.Forms.Application.RunLoop (Boolean Modal, System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationContext context) <0x41017ec0 + 0x0033f> in :0 
>     at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run (System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationContext context) <0x41017e10 + 0x00057> in :0 
>     at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run (System.Windows.Forms.Form mainForm) <0x41017dc0 + 0x00033> in :0 
>     at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.OnRun () <0x4125e9d0 + 0x00077> in :0 
>     at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.Run (System.String[] commandLine) <0x4125e9b0 + 0x00010> in :0 
>     at . (System.String[] ) <0x4125bd50 + 0x00043> in :0 
>   [ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
>     at  +. () <0x4103f510 + 0x001e6> in :0 
>     at njRAT.Form1. (System.Object , System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs ) <0x4103e250 + 0x000ab> in :0 
>     at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnFormClosing (System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs e) <0x4103e1c0 + 0x00065> in :0 
>     at System.Windows.Forms.Form.FireClosingEvents (CloseReason reason, Boolean cancel) <0x4103e070 + 0x0009d> in :0 
>     at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.Windows.Forms.Form:FireClosingEvents (System.Windows.Forms.CloseReason,bool)
>     at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Exit (System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e) <0x4103db20 + 0x001b7> in :0 
>     at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Exit () <0x4103dae0 + 0x00027> in :0 
>     at System.Windows.Forms.Application.OnThreadException (System.Exception t) <0x4103d630 + 0x00147> in :0 
>     at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.OnThreadException (System.Exception e) <0x41040a70 + 0x00013> in :0 
>     at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.WndProc (IntPtr hWnd, Msg msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam) <0x412a8d70 + 0x00b51> in :0 
>     at System.Windows.Forms.XplatUIX11.SendMessage (IntPtr hwnd, Msg message, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam) <0x412a8650 + 0x0044f> in :0 
>     at System.Windows.Forms.XplatUIX11.MapWindow (System.Windows.Forms.Hwnd hwnd, WindowType windows) <0x412ab2d0 + 0x001f3> in :0 
>     at System.Windows.Forms.XplatUIX11.CreateWindow (System.Windows.Forms.CreateParams cp) <0x412a37e0 + 0x00c53> in :0 
>     at System.Windows.Forms.XplatUI.CreateWindow (System.Windows.Forms.CreateParams cp) <0x412a37b0 + 0x0001f> in :0 
>     at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.CreateHandle (System.Windows.Forms.CreateParams cp) <0x412a3700 + 0x0003f> in :0 
>     at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateHandle () <0x412a3420 + 0x00069> in :0 
>     at System.Windows.Forms.Form.CreateHandle () <0x41019c40 + 0x00027> in :0 
>     at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl () <0x412a3170 + 0x00087> in :0 
>     at System.Windows.Forms.Control.SetVisibleCore (Boolean value) <0x412b4bb0 + 0x00083> in :0 
>     at System.Windows.Forms.Form.SetVisibleCore (Boolean value) <0x41019420 + 0x00317> in :0 
>     at System.Windows.Forms.Control.set_Visible (Boolean value) <0x412b4b30 + 0x00032> in :0 
>     at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.Windows.Forms.Control:set_Visible (bool)
>     at System.Windows.Forms.Application.RunLoop (Boolean Modal, System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationContext context) <0x41017ec0 + 0x0033f> in :0 
>     at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run (System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationContext context) <0x41017e10 + 0x00057> in :0 
>     at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run (System.Windows.Forms.Form mainForm) <0x41017dc0 + 0x00033> in :0 
>     at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.OnRun () <0x4125e9d0 + 0x00077> in :0 
>     at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.Run (System.String[] commandLine) <0x4125e9b0 + 0x00010> in :0 
>     at . (System.String[] ) <0x4125bd50 + 0x00043> in :0

Comment: What program? `Directory '/root/Desktop/tool\plugin\' not found` does this directory exist and has proper permissions (ie: is accessible for mono)?

Answer (score 0):

Nothing to do with the warning, but an exception showed later. Your form tries to load an GeoIP file from disk but it uses a Windows only file path which definitely fails on Linux. Learn the file system differences and revise your code.

Comment: I do not understand